# Collecting django static files for deployment

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I developed a django application to handle requests from angular application. Now, should I collect static files for django application while deploying it?

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Will my django respond to the requests without staticfiles? Because, I found in many documentations that collectstatic is being performed in the steps to deploy django application.

Comment: Collect static will get the copy of all the static file in your local system. If you do not collect the static files it will be served as CDN. CDN might not work perfect in multiple scenarios like If you don't have a good connection etc. It is recommended to have static files in your local system so that it can be served fastly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are going to run your Django application. If you are putting it anywhere public, you should have Debug set to False in your `settings.py` and as such you will need to do the collectstatic step, but not necessary every time you make a change; only if you've added more static files.

The 'Serving the files' section of the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) is clear on using runserver in production:

> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is
> unsuitable for production.

Determine what sort of volume your site is going to have to decide if you want something like nginx being your webserver and proxying requests to your Django app being run by Daphne, Gunicorn or uvicon while nginx (or other fav web service) serves up your static content. If it is too much for the one connection or the server it may make sense to host your static files elsewhere - it really all depends on your use case.

Comment: My django application doesn't have any webpages. Instead it is only for handling requests and sending responses. I guess, static files doesn't make any difference.

Comment: In that case, where you have no static files, you don't need to run collectstatic. It goes through your static folders and copies out to your static_root; nothing there needed for general operation if you have no static files.